# send row and column of a matrix, MPI_SEND

Tags: c++, mpi, send

I can send the row of a matrix, and the column of another matrix in a single MPI_SEND, how can I do this procedure?

```
MPI_SEND (row and column of the matrix ...)
```

Comment: Sending a column of matrix with MPI in C/C++ is described in these questions/answers: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788180/sending-columns-of-a-matrix-using-mpi-scatter/10788351#10788351), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371733/how-to-mpi-gatherv-columns-from-processor-where-each-process-may-send-different/5373104#5373104), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512245/mpi-scatter-sending-columns-of-2d-array), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151973/mpi-sending-and-recieving-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

Since C/C++ works in row major order, you can either declare your 2D matrix in a 1D vector and access its entries by using a simple convention. Assuming A is of size mxn and B is a vector;

```
A[i][j] = B[i*n+j];
```

But if you are coding in C++, I would suggest defining a matrix object and try sending these objects in MPI. You would have to create your own MPI_Data_Type.

Comment: You mean the object? It depends on your knowledge on Object Oriented Programming (OOP). Try looking at "C++ matrix objects". If you are in a hurry, maybe you should not follow this path. Reading your response once again, may be you are referring to MPI_Data_Type. You can create you own data type by mpi type commit. You may want to look at PETSc [link](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) which can help you hide all this details regarding the communication.

Comment: I'm not in a hurry, i'm not derail you?

Comment: If you are not in a hurry, try looking at PETSc.

Comment: you have any examples implemented?

Comment: PETSc website has nice examples [link](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/tutorials/index.html). As it is said in the website, you rarely call MPI functions, most of the legwork is done by PETSc.